# 3D Object becomes upside down after export

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal

I'm in unreal engine 5 and I am animating a space ship. When I preview the level sequence, the spaceship's positioning is correct, but when I export, the space ship is upside down and backwards... I created a brand new map, re-did the animation from scratch several times and exported the sequence 16 times and always the space ship is upside down and backwards. Any tips?

This is in unreal engine -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCKJW.jpg)

And this is in after effects. I also can see that the spaceship is upside down WHEN I'm exporting  - in the "low quality" preview window. But ONLY during export.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7iut.jpg)

I created a brand new map, I tried "baking transform", I tried a different level sequence, I tried multiple new camera actors...